Scaling of Production in Chained Producers
wanted some suggestions or vetting on my attempt at the following problem:
The primary resource here is quantity $X$.
A system of chained producers exists where:

there are 8 chained producers, with notation $1<=i<=8$. Producer $P_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ producer.
$P_{1}$ directly produces $X$. $P_{2}$ produces $P_{1}$, $P_{3}$ produces $P_{2}$, and so on, until the production of $P_{7}$ by $P_{8}$.
The number of $P_{1}$ producers is $N_{1}$, and so on. The system may start with any number of producers.
Each producer has a rate of production per producer, e.g. the production of $X$ by each $P_{1}$ is $r_{1}$, the production of $P_{1}$ by each $P_{2}$ is $r_{2}$.

Visually the production chain looks like:
$P_{8}$ → $P_{7}$ → $P_{6}$ → $P_{5}$ → $P_{4}$ → $P_{3}$ → $P_{2}$ → $P_{1}$ → $X$
I'm trying to find an expression for $N_{X}(t)$, the quantity of $X$ at time $t$.

My attempt uses chained substitution.
Only $X$, No Producers
The simplest form is when there there exists no producers, so $X$ does not change with $t$.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{X} = 0
$$
$$
N_{X}(t) = C_{X}
$$
$P_{1}$ → X
$P_{1}$ produces $X$ over time, and is the product of the number of $P_{1}$ producers $N_{1}$ and rate per producer $r_{1}$. $N_{X}$ is now linearly proportional to $N_{1}r_{1}$ across time.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{1} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{X} = N_{1}r_{1}
$$
$$
N_{X}(t) = C_{1}r_{1}t + C_{X}
$$
$P_{2}$ → $P_{1}$ → X
$P_{2}$ produces $P_{1}$ over time.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{2} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{1} = N_{2}r_{2}
$$
$$
N_{1} = N_{2}r_{2}t + C_{1}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}N_{X}(t) = N_{1}r_{1} = (N_{2}r_{2}t + C_{1})r_{1}
$$
$$
N_{X}(t) = \frac{1}{2}C_{2}r_{2}r_{1}t^{2} + C_{1}r_{1}t + C_{X}
$$
General Form
From the above patterns, I extrapolated the general form of $N_{X}(t)$ to:
$$
N_{X}(t) = \frac{\mathbb{R}_{8}}{8!}C_{8}t^{8} + \frac{\mathbb{R}_{7}}{7!}C_{7}t^{7} + ... + \frac{\mathbb{R}_{1}}{1!}C_{1}t + C_{X}
$$
Or:
$$
N_{X}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{8}\frac{\mathbb{R}_{i}}{i!}C_{i}t^{i} + C_{X}
$$
Where $\mathbb{R}_{X}$ is the product of all rates of production at this producer level and below it. For example, $\mathbb{R}_{8}$:
$$
\mathbb{R}_{8} = r_{8} * r_{7} * ... * r_{2} * r_{1}
$$

Would this method of substitution and the general form of $N_{X}(t)$ be correct?
